# CORS header caching with CoudFront and S3

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup CloudFront over S3, and I've run into the following problem.

I'm requesting images and text files across domains. Sometimes the requests to the files are made using XHR, and sometimes by embedding image tags.

The problem I'm seeing is if a request is made to an asset via XHR it includes the '`Origin`' header, and the response has the correct '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`'.  And if I request the same asset after that, not including the '`Origin`' header, it responds correctly with no '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header.  **BUT**... if I make another request via XHR including the '`Origin`' header to the same URL, it returns an incorrect response **WITHOUT** the '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' for ever more.

I have CloudFront setup with whitelisted '`Origin`' headers, and not caching `OPTIONS`.

My S3 CORS policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>60</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And here is a cURL example:

**Make a request via XHR**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Origin: http://www.cnn.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:42:56 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 8d45ffe3c8bfd31eef4b048ab3ea99b2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: lY4reBVHrFq3MVgdFLx4LvbaOj8UnypXIHxBRvUN4TkkXzyHVmQcmQ==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Repeat the request (Note the cache hit)**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Origin: http://www.cnn.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:42:56 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 6
Vary: Origin
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 90d8e168b0948a3eb36a451ebb27f4f9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: cU-TCt-_5MsdLUrUqQk7_HLCUVyNEWOWW2ET19--Pc6j4M-8LkfsyQ==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Make request WITHOUT `Origin` header**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:43:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 bd9375a232718e4567ed228bf8c06fc9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 03bYSXai6AmwmPRHukm3g8Qv09qB-KdyYs5sXb5RLtPuPdYQHD35hA==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0
```

**Repeat request WITHOUT `Origin` header**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:43:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 bd9375a232718e4567ed228bf8c06fc9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 03bYSXai6AmwmPRHukm3g8Qv09qB-KdyYs5sXb5RLtPuPdYQHD35hA==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 3
```

**Make request WITH `Origin` header.  Note missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Origin: http://www.cnn.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:43:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 bd9375a232718e4567ed228bf8c06fc9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 03bYSXai6AmwmPRHukm3g8Qv09qB-KdyYs5sXb5RLtPuPdYQHD35hA==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 9
```

**Same request WITH `Origin` header.  Note missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and Cache-miss**

```
~$ curl 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test/test_03.txt' -H 'Origin: http://www.cnn.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-NZ;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,en-AU;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://www.cnn.com/' -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:43:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 08:41:08 GMT
ETag: "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 bd9375a232718e4567ed228bf8c06fc9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 03bYSXai6AmwmPRHukm3g8Qv09qB-KdyYs5sXb5RLtPuPdYQHD35hA==
Content-Length: 4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 14
```

Comment: There's one really bizarre thing in that last response: how can both of these make sense, together: `X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront` ("Cloudfront did not have a copy of the requested object in cache") ... and `Age: 14` ("This copy of the requested object has been sitting in the cache for 14 seconds.")  I suspect monkey business on the part of your network or ISP.  It is as if there's a badly-behaving, (mostly) transparent cache inline between you and Cloudfront.

Comment: There's no way you should see the same `X-Amz-Cf-Id` on multiple different responses.  If you haven't altered any of these headers, there's something very seriously wrong, here, and I am inclined not to think it's Cloudfront or S3.  See if you can duplicate this with HTTPS, since it's less prone to such tampering.

Comment: Bizarre indeed.  I ran the tests again using SSL, and **it worked as expected!**  Thanks so much for the suggestion @Michael.  This should at least give me a work around.  Any advice on how I might be able to track down the guilty party?

Comment: And to back that up, I repeated the test on another network, in a different region, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Turn on [logging in Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html).  Depending on the setup, the proxy may cause your IP address to be logged differently in the Cloudfront access logs.  You also would see, in this case, fewer requests in the log than you actually made.  Logs take a little while to appear after you enable logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @Michael suspected, this was being caused by some bad intermediary caching somewhere.

Accessing CloudFront over SSL prevented the problem from occurring.